# Form Sign-up with pressing enter

Tags: mailchimp

is there a way to make MailChimp form for Wordpress work like that:

After user types in the email adrress - he presses enter and it will sign him. (So I dont need the button for confirming).

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [MailChimp for WordPress plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/mailchimp-for-wp/) and just hide the submit button through CSS. The form mark-up would look like this.

`<input type="submit" name="Subscribe" style="display: none; " />`